# Oracle query fails by to_date function

Tags: oracle, .net-core, dapper

Using dapper ORM and running this query;

```
string transDate ="to_date('8/4/2023','MM/dd/yyyy')";
string customerProfileId = "5464232";

string query = " update customer_bundle set modified_date = sysdate where cust_prof_id = :customerProfileId and trunc(trans_date) = trunc(:transDate)";

            using (OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection("..."))
            {
                DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
                dbConn.Open();
                dbConn.Execute(query, new { customerProfileId, transDate});
            }
```

it works fine if I remove the "to_date" param from query.

but with date param added, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException throws exception like this;

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00932:
> inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER'

I know somehow this "to_date()" part mapped incorrectly and caused this issue

What's causing this? and how can I fix it? And I am using Dbeaver is there any profiler that I can trace incoming queries from the app? QueryManager doesn't contains external queries..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters given are not inserted as strings into the sql statement; instead, their value is directly used for the query. Therefore, you cannot use the `to_date` function as part of the date literal. Instead, if you want to use `to_date`, you must put it into the sql query instead.

```
string transDate ="8/4/2023";
string customerProfileId = "5464232";

string query = " update customer_bundle set modified_date = sysdate where cust_prof_id = :customerProfileId and trunc(trans_date) = trunc(to_date(:transDate,'MM/dd/yyyy'))";

            using (OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection("..."))
            {
                DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
                dbConn.Open();
                dbConn.Execute(query, new { customerProfileId, transDate});
            }
```